# The meaning of margin of error in a real life example?

Tags: terminology, intuition

I guess I [almost understand the concept of confidence intervals and confidence levels with two real life examples.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/458971/277710)

I still have some difficulties to understand "margin of error".

Image that, in a survey, respondents were asked to indicate their own well being on a scale from 0 to 10, where 10 represents "the best possible life for you" and 0 the worst.

The results stated that the confidence interval was between 4.88 and 5.26 with a confidence level of 95% +/-3, where +/-3 is the "margin of error".

> For the European data, one can say with 95% confidence that the true
>   population for well-being among those without TVs is between 4.88 and
>   5.26. For those with TVs the 95% confidence interval for well-being is much narrower -- between 5.78 and 5.82 -- because of the larger sample
>   size. In addition to sampling error, question wording and practical
>   difficulties in conducting surveys can introduce error or bias into
>   the findings of public opinion polls.

```
- (from ref2 below.)
```

Without the "margin of error", the result means the average well being rating for people is 95% of the times expected to fall within 4.88 and 5.26".

with the margin of error of +/-3, what does that mean?

---

the example are adapted from [ref](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/458974/277710) and [ref2](https://news.gallup.com/poll/105850/ownership-may-good-wellbeing.aspx).

Comment: Ithe interval of 4.88 to 5.26 you quote cannot be a confidence interval, because no parameter is involved. That interval is on the scale of the 1..10 observable, could be some prediction interval, tolerance interval, (but too narrow for that to be plausible.) Maybe something else entirely. Please give a full quote, with source!

Comment: https://www.statisticshowto.com/probability-and-statistics/hypothesis-testing/margin-of-error/

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thank you. I had already attached the source, ref2.

Comment: You should have included the relevant part as a direct quote. I will do it for now!

Comment: ---But that question is still unclear, because ref2 **does not contain the phrase margin of error**, nor anything about those 3%. Please clarify!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thank you. The example is adapted from that source, not directly copy and paste. I made some modification on it, in reference to a [statisticshowto post](https://www.statisticshowto.com/probability-and-statistics/confidence-interval/). I am not sure if I made it up correctly. Would you please give another concrete example, if my OP seems not right to you, I will really appreciate that. Your previously recommended link is just to compute the value without explaining what the values represent in real life.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen For example, your link directly uses the critical value of 1.645 to compute the Margin of Error without any explanation what does 1.645 represent with real life examples. Anyway, thank you, that's very kind of you. I will check it out when I get a clear understanding of the basic concept with some real life examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A margin of error and a confidence interval are pretty much the same thing - it's the interval in which you are quite confident that the true parameter lies. If you have a 95% confidence interval, that means that if you were to repeat your experiment, 95% of the time the true parameter value would fall within your interval. Roughly speaking, there's a 95% chance that the interval contains the true value. The margin of error is simply describing the width of your confidence interval. So, if you have a confidence interval of [4, 6], you can say that your parameter estimate is 5 with a margin of error of 1.

The example you give of "the confidence interval was between 4.88 and 5.26 with a confidence level of 95% +/-3, where +/-3 is the "margin of error"" doesn't make any sense, since the margin of error for the confidence interval [4.88, 5.26] is +/- 0.19, not +/-3. The width of a confidence interval and the margin of error are directly related. One more note, the example of building confidence interval for ordinal rating data (like on a Likert scale from 1 to 10) isn't really advisable, since the scale is not a numerical quantity - you can't say the difference between a 1 and 2 is the same as a difference between 7 and 8, for example. Taking means and deriving numerical statistics on this type of data layers on a number of assumptions that may not hold true.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive explanation. "A poll might state that there is a 98% confidence interval of 4.88 and 5.26", does this example make sense? [source](https://www.statisticshowto.com/probability-and-statistics/hypothesis-testing/margin-of-error/)

Comment: @WXJ96163 Yes, those examples seem correct. A confidence interval has two parts, which are the level of confidence (90%, 95%, 98%) and the width - higher confidence values will generally have wider intervals, since you need a wider range to be more sure you captured the true value. The interval width is basically the "margin of error", which will be given for some confidence value.